# disable all subdomains except pre-defined in htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

The below code disables subdomains, but I can't figure out how to add an exception for a specific subdomain.
I searched for questions on this subject and could not find anything.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Subdomain Exceptions...
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^widgets\.hyperbot\.tv$

    # Disable Subdomains 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.hyperbot\.tv$  
    RewriteRule (.*) http://www.hyperbot.tv/ [R=301,L]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
    RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(gif|jpe?g|png)$       [NC]
    RewriteCond     %{HTTP_REFERER}     !^$
    RewriteCond     %{HTTP_REFERER}     !(www\.)?hyperbot\.tv      [NC]
    RewriteCond     %{HTTP_REFERER}     !google\.                [NC]
    RewriteCond     %{HTTP_REFERER}     !search\?q=cache         [NC]
    RewriteRule     (.*)                -                    [F,NC,L]


    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} proc/self/environ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mosConfig_[a-zA-Z_]{1,21}(=|\%3D) [OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode.*(.*) [OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C).*script.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable all subdomains except one you can use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (^|\.)hyperbot\.tv$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|widgets)\.hyperbot\.tv$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.hyperbot.tv%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you this worked fine, and a clean solution too!

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?mysite\.tld$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Is that for disabling all subdomains?

Comment: Ok, in that case, I tried that, I put it under the exceptions block and it still redirect me.